# Images size in memory cache is higher then real size using Universal Image Loader

Tags: java, android, universal-image-loader

My app has ListView with images. It loads images from internet using Universal Image Loader (1.7.0).

**Configuration and Display Options**:

```
DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheInMemory()
                .cacheOnDisc()
                .build();
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this)
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
                .threadPoolSize(2)
                .enableLogging()
                .build();
```

**Part of getView()** (My app reuses ConvertView and uses ViewHolder pattern):

```
View rowView = convertView;

ViewHolder holder;

if (rowView == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null, true);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.photoView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_photo_view);

    rowView.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
}
String photoUrl = "http://someserver.com/some_image.jpg";
mImageLoader.displayImage(photoUrl, holder.photoView);
```

**list_row.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clickable="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_photo_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:contentDescription="@string/photo"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/template_image_list" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Of course ImageView isn't single view in each row. It's short version :).
So images sizes, that I download from internet is 450x337. I'm testing my app on Tablet with screen size of 1280x760.

As I enabled logging - I see such messages:

```
Load image from memory cache [http://someserver.com/some_image.jpg_1280x736]
```

And so on... I'm a little confused with url ending - "_1280x736". As [second part of manual](http://www.intexsoft.com/blog/item/72-universal-image-loader-part-2.html) says:

> • maxImageWidthForMemoryCache() and maxImageHeightForMemoryCache() is used for decoding images into Bitmap objects. In order not to store a full-sized image in the memory, it is reduced to a size determined from the values of ImageView parameters, where the image is loaded: maxWidth and maxHeight (first stage), layout_width and layout_height (second stage). If these parameters are not defined (values fill_parent and wrap_content are considered as uncertain), then dimensions specified by settings maxImageWidthForMemoryCache() and maxImageHeightForMemoryCache() are taken. The size of the original image is reduced by 2 times (recommended for fast decoding), till the width or height becomes less than the specified values;
>   o Default values - size of the device’s screen.

So, as I understand this ending is the size of image in memory cache after "reduce" :) and image loader had used default value (size of screen). I'm not suprised that image loader couldn't get ImageView's size (maybe too early), but why original image was enlarged? Is it hard to verify original image's sizes and leave them without modifications? Of course, I can add image sizes to displayImage method, but I need explaination...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice detailed question.

URL ending , like **"_1280x736"**, doesn't mean the size of result Bitmap. It's the **target size** for original image to scale down to. In your case it's equal to device screen size and original image (which is smaller this target size) won't be scaled (until you set `ImageScaleType.EXACTLY_STRETCHED` in display options).

So don't worry. If you see real Bitmap size in Runtime then you'll see original image size (not 1280x736).